# create image list from resource file - win32

Tags: winapi, bitmap, imagelist

I have in .rc file several images, for example:

```
IDB_COPY BITMAP "copy.bmp"
IDB_CUT BITMAP "cut.bmp"
IDB_PASTE BITMAP "paste.bmp"
```

And I want to load them all into ImageList.
if I will write

```
HIMAGELIST hImageList = ImageList_LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDB_COPY), 16, 0, RGB(255, 0, 255));
```

it load only the first bitmap, how do I load them all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this code make it:

```
HIMAGELIST hImageList = ImageList_LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDB_CUT), 16, 0, RGB(255, 0, 255));

ImageList_Add(hImageList, LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_COPY)), NULL);
ImageList_Add(hImageList, LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PASTE)), NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11 or above, I recommend using `std::map`.

```
map<string,HBITMAP> hbm; // #include <map>
hbm["CUT"]=LoadBitmap(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDB_CUT));
// ...
// or
map<int,HBITMAP> hbm1;
hbm1[0]=LoadBitmap(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDB_CUT));
//...
```

I think it is more flexible and convenient as images with different sizes can also be accepted.